# Как узнать ID office-процесса, который создался при работе с interop?

Tags: c#, .net, interop

Свойств интересных не нашел.

Пробовал Caption выставлять

```
_app = new Application
        {
            DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone,
            Visible = false,
            Caption = appId
        };
```

А потом по нему искать, но у процесса Word в процессах он пустой...

Comment: А вам это зачем, позвольте узнать?

Comment: Хочу, что бы при смерти основного приложения, оно забирало с собой все фоновые ворды, которые были созданые. Нашел класс для этого даже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed/4657392#4657392

Comment: Так там же и так просто диспойзишь wordApp'ы и приложухи сами закрываются.

Comment: Да, но если что-то где-то упустить, то так висеть и будут.

Comment: Яб вообще от интероп бы отказался. Тащить такую зависимость, тормознутую и не безопасную это.... ну такое. Используйте уже OpenXML

Comment: Да, но есть же файлы старых форматов...*.DOC.

Comment: Сконвертировать их недолго)

Comment: @Сергей, опять же Interop придется подрубать. А что для Docx есть добротного на основе OpenXml? Вот для Excel есть EpPlus. Сам по себе OpenXml сложный, вроде.

Comment: Ну посложнее немного интеропа, да, но ничего сверхъестественного, зато в десятки раз быстрее.